Attribute [Authorize] works only when page is reloaded
I have a Blazor web app with .NET 8. I am trying to configure the app so that certain pages route users to the login page.
I have it working, except that the redirect only happens when I reload the page. I can view the full page when I navigate to it via the nav menu. Once I hit reload I am redirected to login and can verify that I am logged in.
I intended it to have a user redirected to the login page after I click the page that needs authenticating.
Below is my code. I am aware of <Authorized> and <NotAuthorized> and that I can easily throw in a <NotAuthorized> with a child component on my App.razor to manually do the redirect. However, I see no reason why what I have below does not work, and I hope to understand more.
Program.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using MudBlazor.Services;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using WebApp.Components;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var initialScopes = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
// Add Authentication
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services
    .AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services
    .AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

// Add MudBlazor services
builder.Services.AddMudServices();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication(); // Enable authentication
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();


Routes.razor
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>

App.razor
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />  
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

Weather.razor
@page "/weather"
@attribute [Authorize]

<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>

<MudText Typo="Typo.h3" GutterBottom="true">Weather forecast</MudText>
<MudText Typo="Typo.body1" Class="mb-8">This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</MudText>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <MudProgressCircular Color="Color.Default" Indeterminate="true" />
}
else
{
  <MudTable Items="forecasts" Hover="true" SortLabel="Sort By" Elevation="0" AllowUnsorted="false">
        <HeaderContent>
            <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel InitialDirection="SortDirection.Ascending" SortBy="new Func<WeatherForecast, object>(x=>x.Date)">Date</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
            <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<WeatherForecast, object>(x=>x.TemperatureC)">Temp. (C)</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
            <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<WeatherForecast, object>(x=>x.TemperatureF)">Temp. (F)</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
            <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<WeatherForecast, object>(x=>x.Summary!)">Summary</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        </HeaderContent>
        <RowTemplate>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Date">@context.Date</MudTd>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Temp. (C)">@context.TemperatureC</MudTd>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Temp. (F)">@context.TemperatureF</MudTd>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Summary">@context.Summary</MudTd>
        </RowTemplate>
        <PagerContent>
            <MudTablePager PageSizeOptions="new int[]{50, 100}" />
        </PagerContent>
    </MudTable>
}

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Simulate asynchronous loading to demonstrate a loading indicator
        await Task.Delay(500);

        var startDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        var summaries = new[] { "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching" };
        forecasts = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        }).ToArray();
    }

    private class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    }
}


Thank you in advance!

I am very sure that this has to do with this open .NET 8 issue. I can do what I am trying to achieve below (without a refresh) if I add app.MapBlazorHub(), but this leads into the issue I linked.

UPDATE
I updated the code and it should do what you want.
Here is the reason: [Authorize] attribute.

@page "/weather"
@attribute [StreamRendering]
@attribute [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Authorize]

<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <h1>Weather</h1>

        <p>This component demonstrates showing data.</p>

        @if (forecasts == null)
        {
            <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
        }
        else
        {
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                        <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                        <th>Summary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                            <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                            <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                            <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        @code {
        [Inject] private NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn", true);
        }
        }
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>



@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Simulate asynchronous loading to demonstrate streaming rendering
        await Task.Delay(500);

        var startDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        var summaries = new[] { "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching" };
        forecasts = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        }).ToArray();
    }

    private class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    }
}


This is a classic issue, we should use AuthorizeView to protect our content if the user not log in.
Test Result

Here is my test code.
@page "/weather"
@attribute [StreamRendering]
@attribute [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Authorize]

<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <h1>Weather</h1>

        <p>This component demonstrates showing data.</p>

        @if (forecasts == null)
        {
            <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
        }
        else
        {
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                        <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                        <th>Summary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                            <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                            <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                            <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>



@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Simulate asynchronous loading to demonstrate streaming rendering
        await Task.Delay(500);

        var startDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        var summaries = new[] { "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching" };
        forecasts = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        }).ToArray();
    }

    private class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    }
}

Tips
We need to add @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization in _Imports.razor file.


Related link and my findings.
I have tried to use custom BlazorAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler to bypass the issue, but it's not a good solution even it works.

Thank you - as stated I am aware of this, but I am wondering why adding [Authorize] only redirects/works if I reload the page with that attribute?

@NicBolton Updated, please kindly check root cause in official doc and I also update my test code, it can redirect to login page if not sign in.

@NicBolton If you have any concerns about this issue, please let me know.

Again, I'm not interested in <AuthorizeView> components. I am aware of that solution. [Authorize] only working for routing sounds like it is supposed to do what I want it to, and it does do what I want when I refresh the page. I want to know why it doesn't do it when I initially navigate to the page.
